# ArcGIS: How can I convert the cells of a raster to points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, point, convert

I have a raster with 2 rows:

- one with a ton of cells on it,
- the other row with a few cells that I got after using the raster calculator tool.

How I can convert only those cells into points but not all of them?

Comment: You need to explain bit more to get specific answers. What is the range of cells that are required to be converted? You may make use of raster calculator to split them at first. May also clip those using a polygon.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "Extract by Mask" tool to create a new raster layer that only contains the cells of interest, and then use the "Raster to Point" tool to convert the cells of this new raster layer to points.

Here's how to do this:

1. Open ArcMap and add the raster layer that you want to extract cells from.
2. Go to the "ArcToolbox" window and navigate to the "Spatial Analyst Tools" > "Extraction" > "Extract by Mask" tool.
3. In the "Extract by Mask" window, select the input raster layer as the "Input raster or feature mask data".
4. Select the layer or feature class that you want to use as the mask. This can be a raster layer, a feature layer, or a shapefile. Only the    cells that fall within the mask will be extracted.
5. Select the output location and name for the output raster that will be created.
6. Click "OK" to run the tool. This will create a new raster layer that only contains the cells of interest. You can then use the    "Raster to Point" tool as described above to convert the cells of    this new raster layer to points.

Alternatively, you can also use the "Extract Values to Points" tool to extract the values of the cells of interest directly to a point feature class, without creating a new raster layer. This tool is available in the Spatial Analyst toolbox in ArcGIS. To use this tool, follow the steps above to create a mask, and then use the mask as the "Input Features" in the "Extract Values to Points" tool, and the input raster as the "Input Raster or Feature Class". This will create a new point feature class with the values of the cells of interest as attributes of the points.